# LaravelShoppingcart not work in laravel5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, shopping-cart

when i want to install [LaravelShoppingcart](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart) , with composer :

```
$ composer require gloudemans/shoppingcart
```

This return errors.Because composer update laravel version 5.5 to 5.6 and ShoppingCart not work 5.6 yet.How can i install this package with dont update composer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to use Laravel 5.5 or fork the package and bump the version dependencies yourself:

```
// composer.json, 5.5 is the highest supported version
"require": {
    "illuminate/support": "5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*",
    "illuminate/session": "5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*",
    "illuminate/events": "5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*"
},
```

There is a passing pull request in place though:

https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart/pull/425

However, if you can't wait for the pull request to be accepted, the change is trivial.

**Fork the package**

1. Update `composer.json`:

   ```
   "require": {
        "illuminate/support": "5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.*",
        "illuminate/session": "5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.*",
        "illuminate/events": "5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0|~6.0|~7.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "~0.9.0",
        "orchestra/testbench": "~3.1"
    },
   ```
2. Commit the changes.
3. Create a release of your new fork.

**Create a release in GitHub**

1. Go to the page for new fork and click *releases*

[image: Click Releases]

2. Click *Draft New Release*

[image]

3. Give the release a new version (2.4.6 would be used in the example below)

[image]

4. Click *Publish*

You now have a released version in your personal GitHub account which you can instruct composer to use for installation.

**Install the fork using composer**

In the **repositories** section of your `composer.json` add your public GitHub repository:

```
// "repositories" may not exist in your composer.json file.
// add it as a sibling to "require"
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/username/forked-repository"
  }
],
```

and add an entry to the **require** section:

```
// change the version - 2.4.6 - to match your fork's version
"require": {
  "username/forked-repository": "2.4.6"
}
```

You can now run:

```
composer update
```

and the fork will be installed in your application.

Comment: Very well but i dont understand "... and install that" ? How can i install that.Because i can want to install with composer ?

Comment: I've added instructions installing via your personal GitHub

Comment: Thanks for all :))

Comment: Looks like the PR has been accepted - https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart/pull/425#issuecomment-366429415